# Cannot add scrollbars as the content automatically fits to the screen height

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox

I'm trying to center the boxes(which I want to be 80% of the height of the parent component),when I change the height of the browser, the content height Changes as well. I understand that it is 80% which is doing that, but I don't know how to set height so that the content height change with parent height. I want scrollbars to be added when the height changes.

With the content adjusting to changes in height, the entire webpage is getting messed up.
Should I just use a predefined height in pxs instead of using vh?

I'm using Chakra ui and this is the code

```
import { Box } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import React from "react";

const Practice = () => {
  return (
    <Box height={"100vh"} alignItems={"center"} display={"flex"} gap={"20px"}>
      <Box
        width={"200px"}
        height={"80%"}
        border={"2px"}
        borderColor={"black"}
        display={"flex"}
        justifyContent={"center"}
        alignItems={"center"}
      >
        box1
      </Box>
      <Box
        width={"200px"}
        height={"80%"}
        border={"2px"}
        borderColor={"black"}
        display={"flex"}
        justifyContent={"center"}
        alignItems={"center"}
      >
        box2
      </Box>
      <Box
        width={"200px"}
        height={"80%"}
        border={"2px"}
        borderColor={"black"}
        display={"flex"}
        justifyContent={"center"}
        alignItems={"center"}
      >
        box3
      </Box>
      <Box
        width={"200px"}
        height={"80%"}
        border={"2px"}
        borderColor={"black"}
        display={"flex"}
        justifyContent={"center"}
        alignItems={"center"}
      >
        box4
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default Practice;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [css max function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max) like this:

```
<Box
    width={"200px"}
    height={"max(80%, 800px)"}
    border={"2px"}
    borderColor={"black"}
    display={"flex"}
    justifyContent={"center"}
    alignItems={"center"}
    >
    box1
</Box>
```

Comment: but when i open inspector tab, the height of the browser changes and all the content is getting messed up due to change in height.

Comment: Try max function, see edit